# How to get the client device exact ip address using PHP?

Tags: php, ip-address, dynamic-ip, clientip

The below code i tried:

```
<?php
function get_ip_address(){
    foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key){
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true){
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip){
                $ip = trim($ip); // just to be safe

                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false){
                    return $ip;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$result = get_ip_address();
echo $result;
?>
```

It gives an ip address like : 1.23.75.70
It doesn't seems like client device's ip address. It shows the same ip address while executing on all devices.

I want to get the dynamic ip address of the client device where i am execuing this code.

Comment: When you say "client device IP" do you mean the internal network IP? I.e. the one typically assigned via DHCP?

Comment: @apokryfos yes internal network ip only

Comment: That can only be done when the server is set up within the internal network. It is impossible otherwise unless the clients willingly disclose that information (which they don't).

Comment: You mean to say that it will work only on online server? @apokryfos

Comment: No, I'm saying that the internal network IP is only available to other people who are INSIDE the internal network. It is not available to servers which are hosted outside the network.

Comment: As far as I know this information is not available outside the local network  to anyone.

Comment: okay :) @apokryfos

Comment: No, I'm saying that the internal network IP is only available to other people who are INSIDE the internal network. It is not available to servers which are hosted outside the network. @ArunKumar